# TypeError: Cannot read property "shiftDone" from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function ShiftCalcData(theEventId, num)
{
    this.event = theEventId;
    this.numOptions = num;
    this.shiftDone = false;

    if ( this.numOptions == 0 )
      this.shiftDone = true;
    return this;
}
```

This is a "class ShiftCalcData"  defined.
I declared

```
var shiftData = [];
```

and later I add objects to the list

```
shiftData.push( new ShiftCalcData(eventId, count) );
```

and I have a function

```
function getNextShift(numCols)
{
  var min = 100;
  var selCol = 1;

  for ( var j = 2; j < numCols ; j++  )
  {
    var eq = shiftData.length == numCols;
    var tmp = shiftData[j];

    if ( tmp.shiftDone == false )
    {
      if ( tmp.numOptions < min )
      {
        selCol = j;
        min = tmp.numOptions;
      }
    }
  }
  return selCol;
}
```

And I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "shiftDone" from undefined. "
When I look at the debugger, I am sure to see 'shiftDone' properties

I know the code looks "very simple" but I tried too many things...
I am new to writing Google Apps Scripts...

Please

Comment: The error just means you don't have enough elements in the array `shiftData`.  i.e your `numCols` variable exceeds the length of your array, in this case, `shiftData.length`. I would modified the for loop like so, `for ( var j = 2; j < shiftData.length ; j++  )`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how, but the problem was solved (not the lenght of the array). I think it had something to do with permissions